# mysql query help (select latest updates based on timestamp)

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm working on selecting data in a database and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I need to select the latest update

My tables look like this:

```
datatable: userid, userinfo, updated (timestamp);
usertable: userid, username, realname, email, userNumber, Org, SN, Dept.
```

There can be multiple entries in datatable for each user.  For this query I only need the latest entry for each user from datatable:

```
SELECT datatable.userid, 
       datatable.userinfo, 
       datatable.updated, 
       usertable.username 
  FROM datatable 
  JOIN usertable ON datatable.userid = usertable.userid 
 WHERE (....)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT d.userid, 
       d.userinfo, 
       d.updated, 
       u.username 
  FROM datatable d
  JOIN usertable u ON u.userid = d.userid
  JOIN (SELECT t.userid,
               MAX(t.updated) AS max_updated
          FROM DATATABLE t
      GROUP BY t.userid) x ON x.userid = d.userid
                          AND x.max_updated = d.updated
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!  I was getting confused with the subquery and going in circles.

Answer (score 0):

There is function to compare time in the sql query.

I'm not sure how your timestamps is save in db, but if it's a number just look at the MAX() function. If not use the Time or Data function from the sql language to make in into a integer.

For the MAX function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/example-maximum-row.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    datatable.userid, 
    datatable.userinfo, 
    datatable.updated, 
    usertable.username 
FROM datatable JOIN  usertable ON datatable.userid = usertable.userid 
WHERE datatable.updated = ( 
    SELECT MAX(datatable.updated) 
    FROM datatable 
    WHERE datatable.userid = usertable.userid 
    LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY usertable.userid
```

Comment: That will return a random datatable.userinfo, not the most recent (or maybe even an error in strict SQL modes)